# scope.$eval does not work inside link function of custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create custom directive

```
<my-input id="myInputElementId1"
          label="My Label 1"
          ng-model="myInputElementModel1"
          ng-change="resetFormFieldErrors(form.myInputElementId1)"
          ng-required="true"></my-input>
```

which should work like the following:

```
<div>
    <label for="myInputElementId1"><span>My Label 1</span></label>
    <input id="myInputElementId1"
           name="myInputElementId1"
           type="text"
           ng-model="myInputElementModel1"
           ng-change="resetFormFieldErrors(form.myInputElementId1)"
           ng-required="true"/>
</div>
```

**myInput.directive.js** code is the following:

```
"use strict";

module.exports =
    function myInput() {
        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                model: "=ngModel",
                id: "@",
                label: "@",
                required: "@?"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch("model", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) {
                        if (attrs.ngChange) {
                            console.log("Should execute: " + attrs.ngChange);
                            scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            templateUrl: "app/campaign/templates/search/myInput.html"
        };
    };
```

**myInput.html** code is the following:

```
<div>
    <label for="{{id}}"><span>{{label}}</span></label>
    <input id="{{id}}" name="{{id}}" type="text" ng-model="model" ng-required="required"/>
</div>
```

Example of that new directive usage is the following:

```
<my-input id="myInputElement1"
          label="My Label 1" ng-model="myInputElement1"
          ng-change="resetFormFieldErrors(form.myInputElement1)"></my-input>

<my-input id="myInputElement2"
          label="My Label 2"
          ng-model="myInputElement2" ng-change="resetFormFieldErrors(form.myInputElement2)"></my-input>

<my-input id="myInputElement3"
          label="My Label 3"
          ng-model="myInputElement3" ng-change="resetFormFieldErrors(form.myInputElement3)"></my-input>
```

Each time when I change text of input element **console.log("Should execute: " + attrs.ngChange)** works fine, but **scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange)** does not work and execution errors are absent.

Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll need to call `$eval` on the parent scope, so something like `scope.$parent.$eval();`

This is necessary because the `scope` in your directive creates an isolated scope, but `attrs.ngChange` is referencing the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your intention to use scope.$eval, instead I would suggest you the following way which would be the most appropriate way to do based on your above requirement.

```
module.exports =
    function myInput() {
        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                model: "=ngModel",
                id: "@",
                label: "@",
                required: "@?",
                methodChange: '&?'
             }
             controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
               $scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                  if (newValue != oldValue) {
                     if ($scope.methodChange) {
                        $scope.methodChange();
                     }
                  }
               });
             }]
            },
            templateUrl: "app/campaign/templates/search/myInput.html"
        };
    };
```

and replace ng-change with method-change in your directive template

Comment: methodChange is not a case. ng-change can contain any valid code (not only function call w\o parameters).